# Python/OpenCV - Detect lines of basketball court from aerial image

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I'm trying to detect the the outline of the court, however it is not able to pick up the rectangular shape of the image.

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,100,200,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpmJD.jpg)

The detected line is in red which appears only on the right hand side of the image.

*I have also tried HoughLinesP() but it picks up lines that are not required. Have also tried adjusting the threshold and min and max line length.

**[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1hT9.jpg)

Comment: Can you post your input image?

Comment: Edited and posted @GaneshTata

Comment: You just cann't get good result by directly do Canny and hough.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtLA3.png   And you also don't really tell which outline you want to get. All white straight lines? white arclines ?

Comment: I would like to get the outer straight lines, 2 semi-circles and the middle circle.

Comment: @Silencer what do you recommend doing if Canny and hough isn't sufficient ?

Answer (score 0):

Image could have colored channels. Please take help from this.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/squares.py